# How to send Lombok @Slf4j logs and System.out.println() logs to Open Telemetry through Micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry, micrometer, spring-micrometer

My current setup is: a Spring Boot app (version 3.1.5) with Micrometer, sending traces, metrics and (ideally) all logs to an otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib Docker container.

Everything seems working, except I cannot manage to make the Spring Boot app send logs to the OTEL collector.

As I couldn't find very clear instructions on how to do this, I'm just putting things together, for example from these two and others:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/7723
https://github.com/ff-sdesai/distributed-tracing-spring/blob/ee36dcd78ce9c0b517355642af3c5e0b8b6d67d0/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-slf4j/src/main/resources/logback.xml#L17

and hope that it works... but it doesn't, therefore I'm here:

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: always
  (...)
# Micrometer tracing
management:
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0
  otlp:
    tracing:
      endpoint: http://localhost:4318/v1/traces
    metrics:
      export:
        url: http://localhost:4318/v1/metrics
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  (...)
logging:
  pattern:
    console: '[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} [%X{traceId}] [%X{spanId}] - %msg%n'
    level: '%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]'
```

**logback.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property name="LOGS" value="./logs"/>

  <appender name="Console"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>
        %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1}): trace_id: %X{traceId}
        span_id: %X{spanId} %msg%n%throwable
      </Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFile"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/up-user-service.log</file>
    <encoder
      class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>%d %p %C{1} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
      <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/up-user-service-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
      </fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <!-- io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender -->
  <appender name="OTEL"
    class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.appender.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender"></appender>

  <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
  </root>

  <logger name="com.uplight.upuserservice" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="OTEL"/>
  </logger>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
    ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} serviceName: %X{serviceName} requestId: %X{requestId} trace_id: %X{traceId} span_id: %X{spanId} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="OTEL" class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

**pom.xml**

```
(...)
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Adds the Tracing API -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Adds the Tracer Implementation -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Adds an exporter to store the traces -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-logback-appender-1.0</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0-alpha</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-logs</artifactId>
      <version>1.26.0-alpha</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-logback-1.0</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2-alpha</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
(...)
```

**NOTE:** I wondering if this issue is related but not caused by the lack of spanid and traceid in some logs. None of them have them, except for example when I log inside a custom span. This is an example of class trying different features including creating spans:

**TestApi.java**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
class TestApi {

    @Autowired
    private ObservationRegistry observationRegistry;

    @Autowired
    private Tracer tracer;

    @Autowired
    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @GetMapping("test")
    void test() {
        System.out.println("### MY TEST ###");
        log.info("@@@@@ TEST LOMBOK LOGGER @@@@@");
    }

    @GetMapping("exception")
    void exception() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("CUSTOM EXCEPTION");
    }

    @GetMapping("custom_span") // WORKS
    void customSpan() throws Exception {
        Observation observation = Observation.createNotStarted("my-custom-operation", this.observationRegistry);
        observation.lowCardinalityKeyValue("my-tag", "my-value");
        observation.observe(() -> {
            System.out.println("### HOW LONG DID IT TAKE? ###");
            log.info("@@@@@ HOW LONG DID IT TAKE? @@@@@");
        });
    }

    // So, what is Baggage? The spec defines a standard HTTP header to propagate the application-defined properties associated with a distributed request.
    @GetMapping("custom_baggage")
    void customBaggage() {
        try (BaggageInScope scope = this.tracer.createBaggageInScope("my-baggage-key", "my-baggage-value")) {
            System.out.println("### IS IT BAGGAGING? ###");
            log.info("@@@@@ IS IT BAGGAGING? @@@@@");
            log.info("Contains the following baggage {}", tracer.getAllBaggage());
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("custom_metric")
    void customMetric() { // TODO: TO BE TESTED WITH A COMPATIBLE METRIC UI
        log.info("CREATING CUSTOM METRIC");
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        meterRegistry.gauge("list.size", Tags.empty(), list.size());
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
    }
}
```

**config.yaml**

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint:  0.0.0.0:4317
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318

processors:

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

  jaeger:
    endpoint: jaeger-service:14250
    tls:
      insecure: true

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging, jaeger]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging]
    logs:
      receivers: [ otlp ]
      exporters: [logging]
```

Comment: Micrometer does not have much to do with logs here. Spring Boot already integrates with SLF4J, check the OTel docs how to setup the OTel log appender with either Logback or Log4j2.

Comment: @JonatanIvanov Hi, as you can see in my POM, I have already an appender. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I did not say you don't have but you need to check the docs to see how to set them up. Logback/log4j docs and OTel docs should tell it.